# Rails: Is it possible to use a session variable in a rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to know if it is possible to define a value for a session variable in a view page (.html.erb) and use it in a controller?

For example:

in order controller, new.html.erb:

```
session[:amount] = @order.amount
```

in payment controller file:

```
@amount = session[:amount]
```

I have a variable in my controller which its value should be changed based on variable I get in one of the views. As the value is stored in a session, I need to use the session value in my controller. Thank you in advance for descriptions and replies.

Comment: Why don't you just try if this is possible?

Comment: You'd be well advised to set `session[:amount]` not in your view but in your controller.

Comment: @spickermann I tried and I got an error, but I'm not sure if the error is because of this problem or related to other issues!

Comment: @ThomasR.Koll Thanks! and how to pass parameters between views which are for two different controllers??

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: @spickermann It's related to my payment gateway:
Stripe::InvalidRequestError
Invalid Integer

Comment: in that case `@amount.to_f`

Comment: @ThomasR.Koll Still the same error!

Comment: As your error is `Stripe::InvalidRequestError` you should have posted that piece of code where that error is caused.
And btw, Passing on the amount in a session variable to be used in the next request is a terrible habit and should be avoided! Much better to use proper routing for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I tried, I found that it's possible to pass a parameter from a view to a controller using a session variable. The problem I had was due to the type of the variable's value. I used a session variable and changed its type by using the "flood" function, and the problem is solved.

I asked the question in its general form to know more about the session variables but unfortunately I've not received proper answers.

Answer (score 0):

You say

> which its value should be changed based on variable I get in one of
>   the views

How does the view get the value ?

- If you get it by user input:

Using ruby in the view won't help, since the user is interacting with a HTML page. You should use a form POST, possibly asynchronous to make a server call which will set the new value to the rails session.

- If you get it by calculating something in ruby:

Then you could and should probably do it from the controller and not from the view. And yes, you can store values in the rails session.

Also, if you are not sure where your problem is (either session usage or Stripe API usage), I suggest you isolate both problems to figure out a solution.
For instance try setting any hardcoded value in the session in one controller method then reading it in another one. When that works, use it in combination with Stripe.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The problem is solved and as you told it is possible to store values in the rails session.

Answer (score -1):

The problem you are facing is to have a persistence data across multiple requests.

You cannot set a session in the rails view. As the whole principle of session is to have persistent data on the server side. To tackle your problem, you can make use of cookies. Cookies are used for storing persistent data across the request on client side and are sent to the server with each server request. Setting a cookie in your view and using it in a controller will serve your purpose.

Comment: Rails views are templates used by the rails controllers on the server, and `session` is available to them.